# Imenu is missing multi-line golang function signatures

Tags: helm, imenu, golang

When a golang function signature is split with a linebreak it does not appear in `imenu` nor `helm-imenu`. I would like to jump between functions using `helm-imenu`, but this issue is in my way. Not hard-wrapping the function signatures is not a solution because others on my team have other preferences.

For example:

```
// This function does _not_ appear in imenu.
func (b *Foo) LongFunction(ctx context.Context, a A,
    b B, c C) foobar.Bazzybaz {
...
}

// But this one does!
func (b *Foo) ShortFunction(ctx context.Context, d D) foobar.Wazoo {
...
}
```

Short of fixing the problem for me, it would be super helpful if you could point me towards where `helm-menu`/`imenu` gets its symbol list in the first place. Or another package suggestion for fuzzy-searching the file's function list.

emacs 24.5 (9.0)
osx 10.12.3

Comment: See `imenu.el`, variable `imenu-generic-expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the value of `imenu-generic-expression` to

```
'(("type" "^[ \t]*type *\\([^ \t\n\r\f]*[ \t]*\\(struct\\|interface\\)\\)" 1)
  ("func" "^func *\\(.*\\)" 1)))
```

Which has two advantages over the original value. it recognizes split-line functions, and it notices embedded types.

I'll probably submit a PR to `go-mode`, but until then to get this rolling you can do

```
;;; Go mode.
(defun my-go-mode-hook ()
  ; Custom imenu regexes
  (setq imenu-generic-expression
        '(("type" "^[ \t]*type *\\([^ \t\n\r\f]*[ \t]*\\(struct\\|interface\\)\\)" 1)
          ("func" "^func *\\(.*\\)" 1)))
  )

 (add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'my-go-mode-hook)
```

Thanks for the tip about `imenu-generic-expression` Drew!

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution!  Could you please accept your own answer so we can mark this post as done?